# C parsing a string divided

Tags: c, parsing

I hate to be that guy asking easy questions but I am bit rusty in my C and something is eluding me here. I am trying to read a file with the following sample text:

```
    23# 1110.00:1000.00,120.00:1110.00,1190.00:900.00,-52.98,-53.21
```

I want to separate in several strings the elements divided by the cardinal and comas, however in my console am not getting any ouput at all.

```
    #include <stdio.h>   /* required for file operations */
    #include <conio.h>  /* for clrscr */
    #include <dos.h>  /* for delay */

    FILE *fr;            /* declare the file pointer */

    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
        char output[200];
        const char filename[] = "file.txt";
        FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
        if ( file )
        {
            char line [ BUFSIZ ];
            while ( fgets(line, sizeof line, file) )
            { printf(" %s \n", line);

                char * i[80],pt1[80], pt2[80], pt3[80], tp1[80], tp2[80];
                if ( sscanf(line, "%s# %s,%s,%s,%s,%s",
                        &i, &pt1, &pt2, &pt3, &tp1, &tp2) == 6 )
                {
                    snprintf(output, sizeof output,
                            "Leitura:=%s,PT1=%s,PT2=%s,PT3=%s,TP1=%s,TP2=%s,",
                            i, pt1, pt2, pt3, tp1, tp2);
                    puts(output);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            perror(filename);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) will not treat `#` or `,` as delimiters, only whitespace. This means that `"%s"` would read `"1110.00:1000.00,120.00:1110.00,1190.00:900.00,-52.98,-53.21"` entirely, resulting in possible buffer overrun and definitely `6` not being the result.

A solution is to use scan sets:

```
if (sscanf(line,
           "%79[^#]# %79[^,],%79[^,],%79[^,],%79[^,],%s",
           i,
           pt1,
           pt2,
           pt3,
           tp1,
           tp2) == 6 )
```

Additionally, the declaration of `i` is not correct:

```
char * i[80],pt1[80], pt2[80], pt3[80], tp1[80], tp2[80];
```

as it makes `i` an array of 80 `char*`. Change to:

```
char i[80],pt1[80], pt2[80], pt3[80], tp1[80], tp2[80];
```